# Good quality secure VPN tools for home working

Tags: vpn, remote-access

Our company allows us to work from home but we can't take code off our work PCs and, due to various regulations we have to meet, any connection between our home and work PCs must be secure. I'd also like to have multiple screens available at home.

We currently use a Cisco offering to provide remote access to our work PCs but it is slow and keeps on dropping out. Do any of you guys know of any good quality secure remote access software we could use?

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these:

[Remote Utilities](http://www.remoteutilities.com)

[Radmin](http://www.radmin.com)